# how to keep rotation count in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, counter

Given an integer array, which is sorted (in increasing order) and has been rotated by some number k in clockwise direction. Find and return the k.
 code written by me is as below..
im getting wrong results.

```
public class CheckRotation {    

    public static int arrayRotateCheck(int[] arr){
        /* Your class should be named CheckRotation
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * Return output and don't print it.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
         */
      int s=0;
      int next=0;
      int prev=0;
      int mid=0;
      int n = arr.length-1;
      while(s<=n)
      {
        mid=  s+(n-s)/2;
        next=(mid+1)%n;
        prev=(mid-1)%n;
        if(arr[s]<=arr[n])
        { 
          return s;
        }
        if(arr[mid]<=next && arr[mid]<=prev)
       {
         return mid;
       }

        if(arr[mid]<arr[n])
               n= mid-1;
        if(arr[mid]>arr[s])
          s= mid +1;

      }
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you inputs, current outputs, and expected outputs?  It looks like there's a high chance of returning s on the first iteration, which will be 0.  You may want to rethink your algorithm, it looks similar to a binary search, when linear may be easier and more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, if an assorted array is rotated clockwise, all the elements shift to the left. So basically `[1, 2, 3, 4]` becomes `[2, 3, 4, 1]`. And you're trying to find `k` being the number it was moved by. In that example, it would be 1. If so, here's a solution:

```
public static int RotationCheck(int[] numArray) {
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int k = 0;

    //Finding the smallest int
    for(int num: numArray) {
        if(smallest > num)
            smallest = num;
    }

    //Getting new index of smallest int
    for(int i=0;i<numArray.length;i++) {
        if(numArray[i] == smallest)
            k = numArray.length - i;
    }

    return k;
}
```

I first find the smallest value then check its position in the array. Since the array is sorted, the smallest number would originally be the first index.